# Split window upon new C++ class creation in QtCreator

Tags: qt-creator

Is it possible to customize QtCreator to make it automatically split editor with header and code files upon creating new C++ class in QtCreator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly what you asked for but did you know about the **OpenHeaderSourceInNextSplit** command (Ctrl+E,F4)? As the wizard opens up the cpp file automatically it might be good enough to hit that after creation.

[image: OpenHeaderSourceInNextSplit]

Alternatively, You might be able to achieve it by [creating a custom wizard](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html)?

Comment: I use Qt on Mac, perhaps it behaves different on other platforms, but xxxNextSplit commands do split window, moreover, for me it just rotate between header and implementation.

Comment: I suspect, that splitting window doesn't have interface functions for shortcuts and also wizards, so I didn't try to create own wizard because it seems a bit difficult

Comment: I agree that the wizard is not a trivial approach. I just tested on my mac and agree that the command combination doesn't work with the default combination. It did work for me with a different one though. I assigned it to shift+F4 instead, might be worth a try?

Comment: For me it works with just F4, but it does not split the window. Does it split on your Mac?

Comment: Yes I tried it on macOS. It did not work with the default key combination. It did when I assigned the command to a different one inside the **Options->Environment->Keyboard** menu.

Comment: More specifically, Just `F4` is assigned to the **SwitchHeaderSource** command and that works. The **OpenHeaderSourceInNextSplit** command didn't work for me when assigned to it's default key combo of `ctrl+E, F4`. When I reassigned it to a different key combination it did work. I chose `shift+F4`; I've tried other simple key combinations and they also work e.g. not one that requires you to hit one combination followed by another.

Comment: Wow, I've just removed existing keys association and recorder Ctrl+E again and it splits! This is even better that splitting on creating new class, because I can do it at any time. Thanks, Chris!